# Decrypting Unknown Hash Encryption

Tags: mysql, encryption, hash, pawn

I'm moving to MYSQL from files and I want to use md5 instead of Encryption

```
public Encrypt(string[])
{
 for(new x=0; x < strlen(string); x++)
   {
    string[x] += (3^x) * (x % 15);
    if(string[x] > (0xff))
    {
     string[x] -= 256;
    }
   }
 return 1;
}
```

But I need to decrypt it. I don't know how to make a decrypting function. Can anybody help me?

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: @Joni PAWN (pseudo-language of C)

Comment: Do you realize that MD5 is **NOT** reversible? I.e. once you run something through MD5 you cannot recover the original value from the hash.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of PAWN is that it uses null-terminated strings. If that is the case, then this encryption is not a reversable process in general.

Consider a string where the thirteenth character (string[12]) is 'L'. The offset that will be added to that is `(3^12) * (12 % 15)`, i.e. 180. In ASCII, the character 'L' has a value of 76, which when added to 180 is 256. After wrapping to fit in the 0-255 character range that becomes a zero, potentially terminating your encrypted string somewhere in the middle.

If you are storing the length of the original string separately or it's always a fixed length, then maybe this isn't a problem. But if you are relying on a null terminator to determine the length of the string, it isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the "encryption" adds to each character a number derived from its position. The encryption can be undone by subtracting by the same number.

```
public Decrypt(string[])
{
 for(new x=0; x < strlen(string); x++)
   {
    string[x] -= (3^x) * (x % 15);
    if(string[x] < (0x00))
    {
     string[x] += 256;
    }
   }
 return 1;
}
```

Comment: Not working good because i have a text: baqsbaqs <-- Encrypted and decrypted and giving me out a: baqsbaĄsj5

Comment: Not working good because i have a text: baqsbaqs <-- Encrypted and decrypted and giving me out a: baqsbaĄsj5

Comment: What do you get when encrypting `baqsbaqs`?

Comment: baqsbaĄsj5 <--- That string.

Comment: Yes, that's what you get after decrypting. What do you get when you *encrypt* `baqsbaqs`, *before* decrypting?